# Cookies not being set in Spring

Tags: javascript, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, cookies

So I've made a piece of code in the backend that sets the cookie through HttpServletResponse. However, no matter what I do, the cookie won't get stored in the browser.

I've tried-

1. Setting everything to 127.0.0.1
2. Setting /etc/hosts to a second level domain
3. Setting credentials in fetch request
4. Setting Max-Age of cookie
5. Other answers recommended by SO

Here is index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Cookie Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>

            async function getCookie() {

                let response = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8080/getCookie");
                let data = await response.text();
                console.log(data);
            }


            getCookie();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my controller-

```
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@CrossOrigin(origins="*")
public class Controller {
    @GetMapping("/getCookie")
    public String getCookie(HttpServletResponse response) {
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", "Test123");
        cookie.setPath("/");
        response.addCookie(cookie);

        return "Cookie added";

    }



}
```

The request gets sent through, with no errors. However, whenever I check the cookie, it's never set. I've also tried what has been recommended by other SO questions/answers, but nothing works. Also, when I visit the Spring/controller page itself instead of the Apache/index.html page, the cookie gets set. However, when visiting the Apache/index.html page, the cookie doesn't set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code below.
this code to set cookies

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie("name", "Test123");
cookie.setComment("nm"); //optional
cookie.setMaxAge(3600); // sets the cookie expiration, ie. 1hr.
cookie.setPath("/");
cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
cookie.setSecure(true);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: This still didn't work, the cookie value was null when trying to access it on server side.